# store each class in a separate file python

Tags: python, import, module

I'm looking into organizing my modules and classes. All the time I collect my related classes in a relevant module so I can do things like:

```
from vehicles.car import engine
```

In directory vehicles there is a file named car which contains class engine. Clear.

Now I'm looking into the possibility that I can store a class in a file. So I can do something like:

```
from filters import air
```

and the air class is a file on its own. However it's not clear to me how I can have a class named air which is stored into its own file called air.py

If filters.py contained all my classes then this import would work, but that's not what I want.

Any tips or pointers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a directory called `filters`, and files `filters/__init__.py` and `filters/air.py`.

In `filters/__init__.py`, have: `from air import air`, and in `filters/air.py`, define the class `air`.

Then:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from filters import air
>>> air
<class 'filters.air.air'>
>>>
```

Comment: For Python 3, use `from .air import air` (with a dot for relative path) in `__init__.py`